# Azure etting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin failed with exit code 1

Tags: azure, azure-aks

When i am trying to connect to certain pods using

```
kubectl get pods -n aa
```

Getting below error

> error: unknown flag: --environment Unable to connect to the server:
> getting credentials: exec: executable kubelogin failed with exit code
> 1"
>
> Kubelogin - version -- (go1.19.3 windows_amd64) kubectl   - version --
> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21",
> GitVersion:"v1.21.2",
> GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}

Tried

```
kubelogin convert-kubeconfig ./kube/config
```

Again below error

> error: unknown command "convert-kubeconfig" for "kubelogin"

Almost tried everything.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the error you have posted, it seems you have not installed kubectl in a proper way or a right version.
I have tried to install **kubectl tool** on windows machine using below steps to be able to connect AKS cluster.
[image]

```
curl.exe -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.27.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe"
curl.exe -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/v1.27.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe.sha256"
kubectl version --client
```

Kubectl version installed in this demo: 1.27.
As per the [kubernetes doc](https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt), the latest stable version is 1.27.
Refer to this link [kubectl tool install | kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/) for more installation methods.
Next, use **az** module to connect AKS cluster.
[image]

Now verify kubectl tool to list pods.
[image]